# Object no oracle dando como inválido(Invalid)

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Dei um `select * from all_objects where object_name = 'meu_objeto';`. Bem, dessa forma, tive 4 linhas. Duas referentes a `SYNONYM` e isso não me interessa e mais duas linhas: `PACKAGE` e `PACKAGE BODY`. Na linha(tupla) referente a `PACKAGE BODY`, na coluna Status, está `INVALID`. Deve conter erros no código. Como eu debugo ou vejo esses erros no body do package? O meu objeto é um Package.

Comment: Ia remover o post, mas resolvi deixar para os colegas que caiam na mesma situação. descobri o erro. Eu estava atribuindo dentro da function do `package`, assim: minha_var = novo_valor e quando deveria ser: minha_var := novo_valor. Esqueci que em Oracle atribuir é: `:=`

Answer (score 0):

Para debugar um código no oracle, tanto em package como em procedures, functions e etc, você precisa de um programa como o PL/SQL ou o SQL Developer (que é grátis!!!!).

Neles você consegue depurar e testar qualquer uma delas, com debug e com interrupções e etc, desde que o usuário conectado ao banco esteja com DEBUG CONNECT SESSION, um privilégio do usuário SYSTEM autorizado, senão ele não autorizará o debug